# Is nodejs and angularjs are related?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, node-modules

As `nodejs` uses `npm` and `angularjs cli` also uses `npm` for modules.

Is there any relation exists between these two?

Installed `node.js` and tried with `hello.js` simply single line console.log. 
Installed `ng module` and generated a simple angular app and started server using `ng serve -o`, kindly help me to clear doubt, if any relation exists between two.

Comment: Node.js provides an environment to run `javascript` outside browser. Angular code compiles to javascript which is run inside the browser. They are 2 different things. NPM is a package manager to manage dependencies in javascript.

Comment: They are not related at all. But you can serve data from a nodejs backend to a angular frontend.

Comment: Please don't ask questions which are easily available on google search. Do put in some of your efforts. There's endless documents over what is nodeJS, NPM and Angular. https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm

Comment: Think of NodeJS in this situation as msbuild.exe its job is to execute the build scripts and other dev time concerns.

Answer (score 0):

`nodeJs` is for developing backend, `Angular` is for developing frontend

You can have a static web site written with `Angular` and hosting it somewhere like `godaddy` and that is it

If you need to show some data, interaction with database, submitting data,... then you need a backend, one of the platforms for backend is `nodejs`, also you can use `asp.net webapi`, or `java` or ...

Answer (score 0):

**Node** and **Angular** are two distinct entity. In the "web world" there is two distinct things :

- Code running on the client side (running in your navigator), frontend, generally using Javascript/HTML/CSS . This code here is used to design your webpage and interact with the user. There is where angular/angularjs work
- Code running on server side, backend, this is where people use NodeJS. Here you find more logical code used to manage and to store the data thank to database. Here you can use **node express** or **nestjs** to create an http server using node.

Link between both ? Both can communicate using http protocole (we use the angular http client to do that). We simple ask the node server the add/update/remove/calculate data and we play with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Angular.js is a client-side framework that runs in web browsers.

Node.js provides an environment for running JavaScript from a command line.

Angular.js is supported by a bunch of development tools (such as test HTTP servers, and transpilers to convert from TypeScript to ES5). Many of these tools run via Node.js.

You can also use Node.js for server-side programming to support the client-side code in a live environment.